# Specify queue to push on in an Event Class

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1

I'm working with multiple queues and want to push an event to another queue than the default one.

I have a standard event class that implements ShouldQueue, but how can I specify the queue this event will be pushed to?

I have tried with

```
class NewMessageArrived extends Event implements ShouldQueue
{
    use SerializesModels;
    protected $queue = 'redis';
    ....
```

but that doesn't do what I want. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: After spending some quality time with the Laravel source code, I'm fairly sure this isn't possible. Events/Dispatcher.php's `createClassCallable` checks if your class has implements `ShouldQueue`, and if so, calls Dispatcher's `createQueuedHandlerCallable()` method, when in turn queues your event with a call to `$this->resolveQueue()->push()`.

Comment: this is my result for my research, too. I think it would be possible by setting `Config::set('queue.default','redis')` before the event call, but I had some queues that were pushed onto the wrong queue when doing this. I have now changed the way of handling the queues therefor. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. @Ben Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought about changing the default queue, but that just seems wrong and error-prone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Listener:

```
public $queue = 'notifications'; //Queue Name


public function queue(QueueManager $handler, $method, $arguments)
{
    $handler->push($method, $arguments, $this->queue);
}
```

be happy =)

Answer (score 2):

After spending some quality time with the Laravel source code, I'm fairly sure this isn't possible.

Events/Dispatcher.php's `createClassCallable` checks if your class has implements `ShouldQueue`, and if so, calls Dispatcher's `createQueuedHandlerCallable()` method, when in turn queues your event with a call to `$this->resolveQueue()->push()`.

The problem is that push's third argument is what queue to push onto, and that argument is not passed. So it will always use the default queue, so you have no way of specifying an alternate default one.

I recommend queueing the event yourself with something like:

```
Queue::push(
    function() {
        event(new NewMessageArrived());
    },
    '',
    'my-queue'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->queue = 'high';
}
```

I tried to override `$queue` because it public but, laravel `5.6` return errors.

So, set the queue in the class construct is the shortest working solution i found.